# PHP function is_nan() throws a warning for strings

Tags: php, warnings, suppress-warnings

I've been using the `is_nan()` function (i.e. is-not-a-number) to check whether a variable taken from the query string is a number or not. However, in the case of the variable being a string (in which case `is_nan()` should return `TRUE`), the function also throws the following rather annoying warning:

```
Warning: is_nan() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given
```

Since `is_nan()` is for checking if a variable is *not* a number, why would it throw an error for a string? I would have thought that it should accept non-numerical parameters, since that is kind-of it's purpose...

Is there a reason why such a warning would be thrown? Is there some sense that I'm not seeing here?

Note: When the error is thrown, the function still behaves as expected - it returns TRUE for strings and FALSE for numbers. However, I am wondering why it would also throw a warning in the case of a string.
I have also since started using `is_int()` because I have found it to be better suited to my purposes, and so I am not looking for alternatives. I am just curious about this behaviour.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function is intended for checking the validity of return values of mathematical functions and operations (see [NaN@wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)) and expects a float as a parameter. Example taken from the [function's documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php):

```
$nan = acos(8);
var_dump($nan, is_nan($nan));

# prints:
float(NAN)
bool(true)
```

What you probably want is [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php):

```
if (!is_numeric($arbitraryType)) {
```

Answer (score 4):

**[From here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php#62504)**:

> nan/"not a number" is not meant to see
>   if the data type is
>   numeric/textual/etc..
>
> NaN is actually a set of values which
>   can be stored in floating-point
>   variables, but dont actually evaluate
>   to a proper floating point number.
>
> The floating point system has three
>   sections: 1 bit for the sign (+/-), an
>   8 bit exponent, and a 23 bit
>   fractional part. There are rules
>   governing which combinations of values
>   can be placed into each section, and
>   some values are reserved for numbers
>   such as infinity. This leads to
>   certain combinations being invalid, or
>   in other words, not a number.

Answer (score 3):

```
function is_number($a){
    return is_numeric($a) && !is_nan(floatval($a));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A look at the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php) suggests that your understanding of `is_nan()` is incorrect. I think you need to use `is_int()` or `is_float()`. Alternatively you could use an explict cast to convert your variable.

`is_nan()` is a maths function while `is_int()` is a variable handling function.

Comment: Yes, I'm now using is_int(). Looks like you're right. I hadn't been able to find the PHP doc for the function, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because in this situation it has to perform implicit cast. It should warn you. I want to know where implicit casts occur. It is too prone to error.

Comment: mmmm, I see. I was more wondering why the function only accepted type 'double'.

Answer (score 0):

Check:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php

"bool is_nan ( float $val )" <- That's why.

Comment: Right, but that means the function is useless, right? That's his point, I think.

Comment: Yea, I realised that to be the case: the error showed that the function only accepted type "double" or "float". I was asking why this was the case - what was the point of it. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

Do you get the error if you wrap the is_nan() function in a conditional, like:

```
if(is_nan('xxx')) {
echo   "Hey, that's no number!";
}
else {
...............
 }
```

Comment: Yes, that's how I had been using it.